# Undefined index: description

Tags: html

Undefined index of the name description. I am using a div instead of a text area. But it ends into "Undefined index: description" while submitting.

```
< div id="editor-container" class="add-new-post__editor mb-1" name="description" required autocomplete="none">< | div >
```

It end with this output on a browser

> "Notice: Undefined index: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\"

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Shards Dashboards: Blog Add New Post Template
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

'use strict';

(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var toolbarOptions = [
      [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
      ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
      [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
      [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
      [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent         // remove formatting button
    ];

    // Init the Quill RTE
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
      },
      placeholder: 'Words can be like x-rays if you use them properly...',
      theme: 'snow'
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Either indent your code or put it into these characters ` `. It makes it easier to read and understand! Also, I believe your using bootstrap, so add that in your tags.

Comment: Instead of text area I'm using this free plugin cause it looks a little bit nicer.

Comment: what is the purpose of name attribute? did you try to remove it? and check if issue is resolve?